# Security schema .NET

Tags: security, hash

Good day!

I have thought of a security schema for a project and I am curious whether if it is very, very secure.

I have stored in the database a RNGCryptoServiceProvider() base64 string of the GetNonZeroBytes(byte[16] object) method which I use as a Salt.

Next, I use the Salt to generate a Scrypt encryption of the password (just like bCrypt, just that it allows me to chose the quantity of RAM and other stuff like that - in this scenario, I use 8mb of RAM to encrypt the password). I use the output and the Salt from before to initialise a Rfc2898DeriveBytes(encrypted output, Salt, 10000) instance.

```
public static string GetBase64StringSafeString(string SaltSource, string StringToEncrypt, int memoryCost)
    {
        byte[] Salt = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(SaltSource);
        byte[] derivedBytes = new byte[64];

        SCrypt.ComputeKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(StringToEncrypt), (new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(SaltSource, Salt, 10000)).GetBytes(25), (memoryCost != 0 ? memoryCost : 8192), 8, 1, null, derivedBytes);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(derivedBytes);
    }
```

This I use to generate the key and IV for a RijndaelManaged algorithm with a Blocksize of 256. This is what I use to encrypt data into the database and thus to this algorithm, I don't have to store the password anywhere: all I have to do is check whether the password written by the user is good in order to decrypt the data. If it is, the user is authentificated.

Because the main aim of the hacker is to get the data, he needs the password. If he has the password he could either log in and get the data or decrypt the data in the DB. For him to get the password, he would have to run that version of bCrypt with Salt until he finds a match and to decrypt the data from the DB he would have to do that and run the RijndaelManaged with that Rfc2898DerivedBytes.

The only way I see doing this even more secure is by finding a way to store the Salt other than in Plaintext.

What do you think?

Comment: You probably want to ask that in http://crypto.stackexchange.com/